# asp.net delete popup using javascript and c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am bit struggling to understand how it works when you want to delete something using server side. I know how to use MessageBox but it is not ideal. I am advised to use popup on server side.

What I am trying to do is that when you click the button, popup should display to ask you if you are sure you want to delete it. If yes, delete it based on C# delete events. If no, cancel it. How to work with both of javascript and C#?

I got problem When I click the button, popup happens, and when i click yes, delete it which is working BUT when I click no, still delete it. How to handle with yes and no in C# or javascrpit? No idea how to do this.

Your excample code means alot to me. I need to understand. Thanks!!

**Javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var result = confirm("Do you Want to Delete?");
if (result) 
{
    //do ajax call and delete from database
    return true;
} 
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick = " return confirm();" />
```

**C#**

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Delete operation

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html markup:**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
            OnClientClick = " return myConfirm();" />
```

**Js**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myConfirm(){ 
var result = confirm("Do you Want to Delete?");
   if (result==true) 
   {
      //do ajax call and delete from database
       return true;
   } 
   else 
   {
       return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client side:
  function confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
  if (confirm("Do you Want to Delete?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";


        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
            return false;
        }
 document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
```

On server side:

```
    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
         if (confirmValue == "Yes")
     {
     } 
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server button with both client and server events. You can check the client side, and decide weather the server side should be executed or not. for example :

add a CSS class to your button.

```
$('.CssClassOfYourButton').click(function (evt) {
            if (condition)
                return false;
                // Post Back will not happen
            }
            if (confirm('Are you sure? \nDoing this will ......... .')) {
                return true;
               // if user clicks yes ,Post Back will happen and server side delete event is executed. 

            }

        });
```